If $\lim a_n$ exists, then $\lim \inf a_n= \lim \sup a_n = \lim a_n$.
I'm trying to prove that if the sequence $(a_n )$ converges then $\lim\,\sup \, a_n =\lim \, \inf \, a_n = \lim a_n$. Because $(a_n )$ converges take $\epsilon > 0$ then there exist a $N>0$ so that $\forall n \geq N$ we have that $l-\epsilon < a_n < l+\epsilon $. By the definition of $\sup\, a_n $ and $\inf\, a_n$ we have that $\sup \, a_n \geq a_n \geq \inf \, a_n$ and by the definition of least upper bound and greater lower bound we have that $l+\epsilon \geq\sup \, a_n \geq a_n \geq \inf \, a_n \geq l-\epsilon$. So we conclude that $\lim\,\sup \, a_n =\lim \, \inf \, a_n = \lim a_n = l$.
Could you check my proof? I'm doubtful about the last part, from the least upper bound property: $l+\epsilon > a_n $ should imply that $l+\epsilon \geq \lim \sup a_n $ (for the greater lower bound  $\lim \inf a_n \leq l-\epsilon$) so that we have that $l+\epsilon \geq \lim \sup a_n \geq \lim \inf a_n \geq l-\epsilon$ and from this we conclude that $|\lim \sup a_n -l|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$  (the same for the greater lower bound). Does $|a_n-l|\leq \epsilon$ imply $|a_n - l |<\epsilon$ ?.Thank you very much, I'm sorry if my english is not great.

math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

How do you know that $a_n \geq \text{lim inf } a_n$? What about the sequence $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$?

@masiewpao I corrected the proof, I meant that $a_n \geq  \inf a_n$ thank you.

Style suggestion: In a chain of inequalities, increase as you go to the right (to model the usual presentation of the number line).  Of course, formally, it doesn't matter what order you write them in, but many readers parse increasing inequalities faster than decreasing inequalities.  Like any style suggestion, there are infrequent times when the other order is more informative to a reader.
